# Total number of Orders,Total amount and AOV

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have to get total number of order by customer , total value for all those orders,average order value and email . where  from -to dates and Country I have mentioned in where clause. 
This is my table. [Sell-to Customer No_] is customer id.

```
   SELECT 

   [Sell-to Customer No_]
  ,[Bill-to Name]
  ,[Order Date]
  ,[Amount]
  ,[Original Order No_]
  ,[Country]
  ,[Email]
  FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Dreams$Internet Orders]
  WHERE [Country]='RUSSIA' and 
  [order date] >= '2016-11-18T00:00:00.000' AND 
  [order date] <= '2017-04-10T00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Hint:  `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, `AVG()`.

Comment: @Giridhar,What you tried..?

Comment: I have tried count() and sum() but as i am new to SQL bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through what's happening in SQL aggregation. Assuming you understand the reference to the table, and what's happening in the WHERE clause, I'm just going to talk about *aggregate* functions and GROUP BY.

Aggregates are fairly straightforward functions that apply to all the rows in your query, prior to grouping. So in other words, if you write a query like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable
```

The aggregate function counts all the rows in the table. *sum*, *avg*, are also aggregates. If you want to see counts for various subsets within the table, you need to provide a GROUP BY qualifier. This changes the aggregate to count the number of rows for each email.

```
SELECT email, count(*) FROM MyTable GROUP BY email
```

Note that we have to explicitly refer to email in the SELECT, as well as in the GROUP BY.

So to answer your question, I think you need a query like this.

```
SELECT 
    [Email]
  , COUNT(*)                AS order_count
  , SUM([Amount])           AS total_amount
  , AVG([Amount])           AS avg_amount
FROM 
  [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Dreams$Internet Orders]
WHERE 
  [Country]='RUSSIA' 
  AND [order date] >= '2016-11-18T00:00:00.000'
  AND [order date] <= '2017-04-10T00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY
  [Email]
```

Just one other thing to be aware of WHERE is applied prior to aggregation, so it can't be used to filter your grouped results. If you needed to do something like filter down to emails that had more than 2 orders, you would add a HAVING clause to the very end of the query like so:

```
...
HAVING
  count(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
SELECT 

   [Sell-to Customer No_]
  ,Count(*)
  ,Sum([Amount])
  ,AVG([Amount])
  FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Dreams$Internet Orders]
  WHERE [Country]='RUSSIA' and 
  [order date] >= '2016-11-18T00:00:00.000' AND 
  [order date] <= '2017-04-10T00:00:00.000'  
group by [Sell-to Customer No_]
```

and if you want other column please get it via first, max, sum.... functions depends on your requierment

if every customer has one email in your grouping values you can add column like this

```
SELECT 

       [Sell-to Customer No_]
      ,[Email]
      ,Count(*)
      ,Sum([Amount])
      ,AVG([Amount])
      FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Dreams$Internet Orders]
      WHERE [Country]='RUSSIA' and 
      [order date] >= '2016-11-18T00:00:00.000' AND 
      [order date] <= '2017-04-10T00:00:00.000'  
    group by [Sell-to Customer No_], [Email]
```

if no and you for example want to show first email from  grouping values you can use `first_value` like this

```
SELECT 

       [Sell-to Customer No_]
      ,FIRST_VALUE([Email]) over (partition by [Sell-to Customer No_] order by [Sell-to Customer No_] ) as Email
      ,Count(*)
      ,Sum([Amount])
      ,AVG([Amount])
      FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Dreams$Internet Orders]
      WHERE [Country]='RUSSIA' and 
      [order date] >= '2016-11-18T00:00:00.000' AND 
      [order date] <= '2017-04-10T00:00:00.000'  
    group by [Sell-to Customer No_]
```

Comment: Please how to email populated in the results as well .

Comment: , it's is working but i just need to get email as well in the results.

Comment: give me 1 minute

Comment: i have changed my answer please look it

Comment: Thank you Mikuana , @Vecchiasignora both are working good. You guys are magic.